$SHELL points to bash instead of zsh in VSCode with SSH
I use VSCode with the Remote - SSH extension to ssh into my Linux server. The default shell on the server was bash and I wanted to change it to zsh. I installed zsh and changed the default shell using chsh -s $(which zsh). To my surprise, when I opened the integrated terminal, I got into bash again. I found that I need to change the default terminal profile to zsh so I added the setting "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh" to my remote settings. Then a new terminal spawned zsh as I wanted, but I faced another problem.
When I ran echo $SHELL, I got /bin/bash instead of zsh:

This is a problem because I have a custom function that creates a custom environment in a subshell using exec $SHELL. So running this function gives me a subshell of bash even though I called the command from zsh.
I know it's a problem with VSCode and not with my server's configuration because if I ssh into the server using a regular terminal or any other ssh client, the value of $SHELL is zsh as it's supposed to be:

I searched the settings of VSCode and couldn't find anything that could help me, especially since the default terminal profile is already set to zsh, so I don't know what I am missing.

Do you have devcontainers enabled in VS Code? The simple explanation is if your shell is in Docker and not the host.

@CharlesDuffy I don't know, but I think not. I have Docker installed, but I don't use it often. In addition, the connection is in the Remotes - (Tunnels/SSH) tab and not the Dev Containers tab.

Where exactly did you execute the chsh command? It sounds vaguely like you did so on your local machine, not the remote server.

Nope. I executed it in the ssh session. Again, logging with a regular terminal or ssh client confirms that zsh is set correctly.

If chsh isn't reflected on a remote host, talk to the sysadmin of that remote host -- it's not a VS Code problem, and thus not something we can help with here. On a lot of sites that use remote directory stores (LDAP, Active Directory, NIS, etc), chsh isn't even wired up to be able to change account configuration.

Could it be that your VSC was invoked by bash, or by a process which had somewhere up the parents a bash process? In this case, bash would set SHELL to bash, since this is an environment variable, it sticks there. You could do a export SHELL==zsh in your .zshrc to fix this.

You probably have vscode processes still running on Linux server, try to terminate them :
pkill -f "$HOME/.vscode-server"

Regarding -zsh, from man zshall :

LOGIN (-l, ksh: -l)
      This is a login shell. If this option is not explicitly set, the shell becomes a
      login shell if the first character of the argv[0] passed to the shell is a `-'.


It's one of the default profiles of VSCode.

I think your update was the solution. I restarted my connection to the server, which probably killed the vscode processes too, and now in vscode, both $SHELL and $0 give me /usr/bin/zsh.

One weird thing is that in a regular terminal, $0 gives me -zsh instead of /usr/bin/zsh. What's the difference?

I think the leading dash indicates a login shell.
